# Convert IQueryable<T> to IQueryable<Y>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I'm try to do this : I'm using EF code first to map an old existing database. There's many fields with the wrong type (ex: char(1) used as boolean) so I've created a wrapper class for my db context that maps perfectly to the database table. Now, I want to expose an IQueryable of my Entity type on my repository. See my example :

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WrappedEntity> WrapperEntities;
}

public class Repository
{
    private MyContext _context;

    //contructors omitted

    public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities()
    {
        return _context.WrapperEntities; //doesn't compile, I need some convertion here
    }
}
```

I already have my convertion routine, the only thing missing is a way to query my DbContext thought my repository without exposing the WrappedEntity class, Is it possible and how ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, you created the WrappedEntity type to correct some unfortunate schematic decision in the database, but then you don't want to expose that? Am I reading you correctly?

Comment: Exactly. I want to "hide" from the consumer of my repository the real structure of my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you project with `Queryable.Select` to change the type of your query...

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities()
{
  return _context.WrapperEntities.Select(x => new Entity(){...});
}
```

Comment: Closest to what I needed but I realized that what I wanted was not the best way to solve my problem. Thanks for your help.